# How can I get real-time alerts in case of PHP out of memory errors?

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have several Wordpress sites and I'm trying to figure how could I setup a monitoring system to get real-time alerts in case of PHP out of memory errors (Fatal errors).
Both paid (commercial) and free tools.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just use another server to run a PHP script getting content of say the front page of your site, and if it detects some problems (say some keywords missing) then send an alert email to you.

Comment: You mean to check for server uptime? For that I'm already using StatusCake alerts.
I'm looking for something that could allow to receive alerts in case of PHP out of memory errors!

Comment: Checkout Bugsnag for error reporting, NewRelic for tracing. You can setup alerts to monitor on key performance metrics in NewRelic. Sentry also provides similar capability